# Not getting input data stream when execute another process from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

I am new to java and i am calling a Python script from java using  processbuilder and trying read python output in java.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("python","PyScript.py",""+path));
Process p = pb.start();
String line;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    logger.debug("Value of python output is"+line);
    System.out.println("in while loop");
}
```

readline is getting null. when i run through command prompt its running fine.

Comment: try p.getErrorStream() just in case

Comment: readline `Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.` Maybe your python script does not write any \n or \r?